# Webpack 5 upgrade and module not found error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-5

I am getting below error after updating webpack5 with respect to React module compilation.

With webpack 4 we were able to refer few node modules outside of sr/ folder using path.resolve and path.join. But now thats not working.

**Module not found: Error: You attempted to import file s which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.**